# How to handle git for multiple projects (folders) in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I tried opening multiple folder in Visual Studio Code, it works fine. But git doesn't seem to work for every other folders.

Comment: Are those folders within a git repository, or repositories themselves? What does *"doesn't seem to work"* mean, exactly?

Comment: There is a parent folder which contains another child folders. There folders are within their respective git repository.

Comment: I have `root` folder is a git repo, and every children folders is a repo and `vscode-git` is only work for `root` folder.